# pymc3 - how to add HDI to traceplot?

Tags: matplotlib, bayesian, pymc, pymc3

Is there a build-in way to add Highest Density Interval to traceplot in pymc3?

I would like to display the HDI on my traceplot directly, ideally with labels.
Basically, I would like to produce a posterior distribution plot, similar to those in "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis" book:
[image]

I don't want to re-invent something that might be implemented in pymc3 already.

Comment: There's currently no built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built-in way but you can check the code [here](https://github.com/aloctavodia/Doing_bayesian_data_analysis). Specially [plot_post](https://github.com/aloctavodia/Doing_bayesian_data_analysis/blob/master/plot_post.py)

**Update**

A function (`plot_posterior`) to make this plot has been added to PyMC3.

Comment: Yeah, I've added it.

Comment: @volodymyr.yep I know. The update was intended for others that could reach the question